# Run exe with PS Core code in the PS Core shell instead of Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell-7.0

Would it be possible for me to make an exe with PS Core code run in PowerShell Core instead of running in Windows PowerShell?

Comment: This would entirely depend on the method you are using to convert the PowerShell script into an executable. What method is that?

Comment: @Ramhound The ps2exe module.

Comment: I don't have the time to research the subject, how the ps2exe module works exactly, but it will probably be based on which version of the PowerShell calls the ps2exe module.  It might require to update ps2exe to support PowerShell 7.1